# using lftp to upload to ftp site got 501 Insufficient disk space

Tags: ftp, lftp

I'm new to using ftp and recently i came across this really wired situation.

I was trying to upload a file to someone else's ftp site, and i tried to use this command

```
lftp -e "set ftp:passive-mode true; put /dir/to/myfile -o dest_folder/`basename /dir/to/myfile`; bye" ftp://userName:passWord@ftp.site.com
```

but i got the error

> put: Access failed: 501 Insufficient disk space : only 0 bytes available. (To dest_folder/myfile)

and when i log on to their site and check, a 0 byte file with myfile name is uploaded.

At first i thought the ftp site is out of disk space, but i then tried log on to the site using

```
lftp userName:passWord@ftp.site.com
```

and then set passive mode

```
set ftp:passive-mode true
```

and then upload the file(using another name)

```
put /dir/to/myfile_1 -o dest_folder/`basename /dir/to/myfile_1`
```

this time the file was successfully uploaded without the 501 insufficient disk space error.

Does any one know why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: You might try using `lftp -d`, to enable the debug/verbose mode.  Some FTP clients use the `ALLO` FTP command, to tell the FTP server to "allocate" some amount of bytes in advance; the FTP server can then accept/reject that.  I suspect that `lftp` is sending `ALLO` to your FTP server, and it is the FTP server responding to that `ALLO` command with a 501 response code, causing your issue.

Comment: @Castaglia Thank you! I did a -d and indeed as you said, the lftp tried to ALLO and that's where it failed, after i disabled it now i can upload file successfully, but it also send a MFMT command but i don't have the permission to do that, I didn't find any information on lftp that i can disable this command. do you have any knowledge on that? Thanks!

Comment: You might try `set ftp:use-feat no` and/or `set ftp:trust-feat no`; most times, FTP servers announce their support for `MFMT` via the `FEAT` response, so by telling `lftp` not to ask for `FEAT` (or trust it), that _might_ work.

Comment: @Castaglia actually, by default, lftp set trust-feat to false, and i set use-feat to false too, now it didn't send the MFMT command, instead it send the SITE UTIME and returned a Unknown command error. Is lftp will always want to set the file modification time? seems like it is trying to find a way to do so...

Comment: I was looking for a way to disable that `lftp` behavior, but didn't find a way.  So you might also try `set ftp:use-site-utime no` _and_ `set ftp:use-site-utime2 no`.

Comment: @Castaglia got it, thank you for your patience! If you have time to make it into an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using `lftp -d`, to enable the debug/verbose mode. Some FTP clients use the `ALLO` FTP command, to tell the FTP server to "allocate" some amount of bytes in advance; the FTP server can then accept/reject that. I suspect that `lftp` is sending `ALLO` to your FTP server, and it is the FTP server responding to that `ALLO` command with a 501 response code, causing your issue.

Per updates/comments, the OP confirmed that `lftp`'s use of `ALLO` was indeed resulting in the initially reported behaviors.  Subsequent errors happened because `lftp` was attempting to update the timestamp of the uploaded file; these attempts were also being rejected by the FTP server.  `lftp` had tried using the `MFMT` and `SITE UTIME` FTP commands.

To disable those, and to get `lftp` to succeed for the OP, the following `lftp` settings were needed:

```
ftp:trust-feat no
ftp:use-allo no
ftp:use-feat no
ftp:use-site-utime no
ftp:use-site-utime2 no
```

With these settings, you should be able to have `lftp` upload a file *without* using the `ALLO` command beforehand, **and** *without* trying to modifying the server-side timestamp of the uploaded file using `MFMT` or `SITE UTIME`.

Hope this helps!